# Is 'All of my first attempts did not succeed' equal or close to the meaning of 'None of my first attempts succeeded'?

Tags: meaning

I would say that the former one means the same as 'Not all of my first attempts succeeded' and 'Some of my first attempts failed'. I don't have a persuasive answer as to why.

Comment: Because that's the way that colloquial English (as opposed to mathematical logic) works.

Comment: The first one is ambiguous.  It could mean, "Not all of my first attempts succeeded,"suggesting that some did.  It could also mean, "None of my first attempts succeeded," meaning there weren't any that didn't.

Comment: Note that *did not succeed* doesn't necessarily mean *failed*. Perhaps something is still in progress, and the result is still not known. Or the result could be something ambivalent—neither success nor failure.

Comment: Some pin the blame on Shakespeare. Something to do with [gold and glitter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_that_glitters_is_not_gold).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a matter of dialect; English speakers differ.  This is a well-known and well-studied matter in English.  See for example https://books.google.com/books?id=-7ADDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=neg-q+dialect&source=bl&ots=vQQOPL5xgv&sig=ACfU3U0wLxSe9bdn_cJRrH7MwD6zFF06Jg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUooqN2p7kAhVXsp4KHVusDJ4Q6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=neg-q%20dialect&f=false and references therein.

Comment: I see mostly a jumbled mess of letters and numbers... could you not select a few of the examples cited in the book? I could embed the link for you to make it look tidier.

Comment: Link-only answers are verboten. Could you add the relevant sections?

Comment: Such references to Google books look messy, but they work.  The url I gave includes search info that goes to the right place in the book and highlights the relevant passages.  I just tried clicking the link.  It worked fine.  @Mari-LouA, did you try clicking the link?  It's not meant to be read; it's meant to be clicked.  Nonetheless, I'll look up another reference, in a few minutes, for those who can't use this one, for some reason.

Comment: @marcellothearcane, I've added an alternative url for the individual paper and section info, for you.

Comment: It looks horrible, it looks a mess, but I knew it worked. I suggested that you select an excerpt (and include it IN the answer)  so that the answer is self contained. Links rot over time, sites move, sometimes sites even disapear. The same request was made by marcellothearcane, but you only changed the url address. Have you never seen answers on SE  that cite a particular passage but also include an embedded link?

Comment: @GregLee This is a fine answer, but it could be better.

Comment: I seem to have lost control over what is in the answer I gave, since someone has changed it.  I added another link, referred to in a comment, but this is gone.  Please, no one should assume that this is my answer, any longer.  I'll probably come back and delete the whole mess, if I can.

Comment: If you found [**the edit**](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/509541/3), which didn't change your answer because the explanation was untouched, harmful, you can rollback the edit to the first version. Just open the first window and click on rollback https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/509541/revisions

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Thank you for the suggestion.  I've restored my own answer.