# How many can be "first" or "last?"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

[A question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509530/is-all-of-my-first-attempts-did-not-succeed-equal-or-close-to-the-meaning-of) asked by Lupilum about "all" or "none" of his "first" attempts prompted me to think of two common expressions that always make my head spin. We often hear "one of the first" or "one of the last." My thinking and my dictionary say there can be only one item or event in "first" or "last" place; unless you specify a tie or you indicate the "first five" or the "last group." Am I wrong to be dizzied by this usage?

Comment: This can be pretty broad depending on the circumstances. 'One of the first' out of twenty contestants is going to include less than out of twenty thousand.

Comment: "One of the first things I think about is..." I might think of different things at different times, but only one such thought was first on each occasion. For example my first thought might be *This is too soon* on some occasions, or *Is this enough?* on other occasions. These are two of the "first thoughts" I might have.

Comment: On five separate occasions, each an occasion where something different was attempted , a "first attempt" was made. Therefore, across those five occasions, there were five *first attempts* made. That addresses the original issue. For the other, it's assumed that a number is part of the statement.

Comment: @Cascabel The post referenced is [Is 'All of my first attempts did not succeed' equal or close to the meaning of 'None of my first attempts succeeded'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509530/is-all-of-my-first-attempts-did-not-succeed-equal-or-close-to-the-meaning-of), and the username of the original poster is Lupilum.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, I looked that user up after a fruitless search on the internet for a scholar named Lupilum. It was intended as a gentle nudge for the OP to edit.

Answer (score 1):

> My thinking and my dictionary say there can be only one item or event in "first" or "last" place

There can be more than one "first" or "last" thing. You've already given two examples yourself ("first five", "last group", and ties). This concept is applicable in more contexts, not only in the exact kinds of phrases that you gave. As Jason Bassford said in a comment, the number is assumed rather than stated in other phrases; for example, "the first few minutes of an exam" ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/first?q=first_1)) or "the first responses to my question came yesterday".

The expressions "one of the first" and "one of the last" are simply combinations of the "one of the" structure with the uses of *first* and *last* to refer to groups or collections of items.

The meaning of a word isn't derived from its dictionary definition, but Cambridge's definition A1 does fit pretty well with this use of *first*: it is "coming before all others in order, time, amount, quality, or importance". When you consider a group, "all others" generally does not refer to other members of the group; rather, what it means to say that the members of the group are "first" in something is that they come before anything or anyone not in the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about people, consider that they are in a queue, ordered by arrival time, test score, or some other metric.  This ordering is from "first" to "last".  Now, if there are 100 people and you want to specify 50 of them, starting from the head of the queue, you could easily say "the first half".  Or if only 10 you could say "the first 10".

And saying "one of the first", while not terribly precise (absent some additional implied criterion), simply refers to someone near the head of this queue.  How near is subject to interpretation.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this sort of nomenclature.  Yes, at times it lacks precision, but so does about 95% of English speech -- comprehension is possible thanks to context and precedent.